# I have installed and configured all perfectly about apache2, passenger,but this times out to rails app on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Let me show my Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.4.1"

gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
gem 'puma'
gem 'pg'
gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.11.0"
gem 'd3_rails'
# Auth
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

# Front-end
gem 'react-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jbuilder'

gem 'friendly_id'

# Image upload
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog'
gem 'net-ssh'
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc

# Load will_paginate before elasticsearch gems.
gem 'will_paginate'

# Elasticsearch
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'

# Background Job
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
# gem 'sidetiq', '~> 0.7.0'

gem 'nokogiri'

# Caching
gem 'dalli'
gem 'bundler-audit'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'awesome_print'

  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rails_best_practices'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require: false
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'bullet'

end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails'
end
```

There is no error when I install gems, and  configured perfectly about Passenger and Apache2 Server. It means when I deploy my rails app, no error.

And I will show apache error.log

```
 N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3272 883/T5 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3274 883/T3 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3275 883/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:531 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3352 2202/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1283 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3496 2206/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1083 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3497 2206/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:248 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3574 2206/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:830 ]: Passenger core online, PID 2206
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3742 2212/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:537 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3750 2212/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:350 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 2212
[Thu Sep 21 12:26:00.376239 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18263:tid 140438528898944] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 21 12:26:00.376261 2017] [core:notice] [pid 18263:tid 140438528898944] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.5539 877/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:02.8255 2206/T8 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:374 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
App 2289 stdout: 
App 2289 stdout: BONSAI_URL not present, proceeding with Elasticsearch defaults.
App 2430 stdout:
```

So I test sample rails project because I can't understand why this times out to my proejct on AWS. As a result it works correctly.

I'll show the conf file of the simple project.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName ec2-34-229-186-158.compute-1.amazonaws.com    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
   DocumentRoot /var/www/simple/public    
   PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/wrappers/ruby    # Relax Apache security settings
   <Directory /var/www/simple/public>
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews
     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Only my rails app of deployment doesn't work.

Anyone help me? :)

Comment: AWS EC2 instances has its own security groups. You need to allow your port in settings. Are you sure that the port is open?

Comment: yes, it is open. I have configured perfectly

Comment: does your app expect `BONSAI_URL` to be set in the `ENV`? If so have you edited the apache env file to add it?

Comment: Also just some advice, saying you did something perfectly isn't as reassuring as you might think. You are better off giving examples of what you did, so that others can see whether you did it correctly or not.

Comment: "BONSAI_URL not present, proceeding with Elasticsearch defaults " This can effect the deployment?